# Why does 始末に負えない mean "difficult/impossible to handle"?

Tags: meaning, particle-に

Each of 始末 and 負う has several meanings. What meanings do they have in 始末に負えない? And what usage of に is being applied here?

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of all the senses that are possible for each of the individual terms is likely leading to a mish-mash of confusing ideas.

Considering the meaning of the total phrase, we can work backwards to figure out which meanings must be relevant for the pieces.

- 始末【しまつ】に負【お】えない
  *"impossible to handle, can't manage"*

From this phrasal meaning, I look up each of the parts in my local copy of the *Shin Wa-Ei Chū-Jiten*.  Here are the fitting senses:

- 始末【しまつ】: *"an end to something: settlement, dealing with, putting in order"*
- に: indicating direction of action: *"to"*
- 負【お】えない: negative potential form of verb 負【お】う, *"to bear or shoulder a burden, to take responsibility for something"*

Literally, and horribly clunkily, 始末に負えない could parse out in English to something like *"cannot bear [something] to its settlement"*.

More colloquially, we might say *"cannot carry [something] through [to its conclusion]"*.

Even more simply, we might say *"cannot carry it through"*.  Depending on the phrasing, we could change this to describe the thing (rather than the abilities of the person) as *"not manageable, not feasible"*.

Comment: It’s interesting to note that its synonym 手に負えない has a very similar structure but this に seems to have a different function from the one you attribute to the particle in 始末に負えない. Do you see any possibility that the phrase started as a misuse of 手に負えない and 始末に困る or something?

Comment: @aguijonazo – I don't see the に as too far apart between 始末に負えない and 手に負えない.  For the latter, I think that's translatable as (and not that far from) English expresssion _"cannot get something in hand"_, where _"in hand"_ means _"in control, handled"_.  いかがでしょうか。

Comment: I see the に in 手に負えない the same way I do the に in 手に持つ or, to use the same verb (in a more literal sense), 背に負う. You hold or bear something in or on the indicated part of the body (essentially “place”). I find it hard to explain 始末に負えない by this function of に.